# Cannot deploy flask app on Passenger running in centos7

Tags: nginx, flask, passenger, centos7

I am trying to deploy a `flask` application on a centos7 using Phusion's Passenger and `Nginx`. I can run my app in flask, on the server, but I am unable to access the app. 
I have followed all the steps in [phusion guide](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/python/ownserver/nginx/oss/el7/deploy_app.html)

`Flask` app is created as follows:

```
import os

from flask import Flask, send_from_directory


def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    DATABASE_FILE = os.path.join(app.instance_path, "myapp.sqlite")

    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY="key",
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='mysql+mysqldb://user:password@localhost:3306/db',
        SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS=False,
        FLASK_ADMIN_SWATCH= 'cerulean',
    )

    if test_config is None:
        app.config.from_pyfile("config.py", silent=True)
    else:
        app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

    try:
        os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
    except OSError:
        pass

    @app.route("/favicon.ico")
    def favicon():
        return send_from_directory(
            os.path.join(app.root_path, "static/favicon"),
            "favicon.ico",
            mimetype="image/vnd.microsoft.icon",
        )

    from myapp.model.auth_model import db
    db.init_app(app)

    from myapp.controller import session
    session.init_app(app)

    from myapp.view import auth
    app.register_blueprint(auth.bp)
    from myapp.view import module1
    app.register_blueprint(module1.bp)
    app.add_url_rule("/", endpoint="index")
    from myapp.view import api
    app.register_blueprint(api.bp)

    return app
```

As for the Passenger WSGI file (`passenger_wsgi.py`), having no better idea, I just have this code placed in the application folder:

```
import myapp
application = myapp.create_app()
```

The nginx `error.log` show the following

```
App 5979 output:   File "/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 333, in process_request
App 5979 output:     result = self.app(env, start_response)
App 5979 output: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

HELP!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I deployed the app successfully.
I had to do three things:

1. return the app correctly from the app factory
2. place the passenger_wsgi.py file in the app/code folder
3. make sure the correct version of python is called

the app factory is now this...

```
    ...

    from myapp.view import auth
    app.register_blueprint(auth.bp)
    from myapp.view import module1
    app.register_blueprint(module1.bp)
    app.add_url_rule("/", endpoint="index")
    from myapp.view import api
    app.register_blueprint(api.bp)

    return app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    app.run()
```

/var/www/app_name/code/passenger_wsgi.py file is as follows

```
from nwpapp import create_app
application = create_app()
```

I have not used virtual environment. by default, python2.7 is invoked. I had to set alternatives and made python3.6 the default. Be sure to run the correct pip version to install your dependencies.